# What is Eta squared? what Eta squared measures?

Tags: effect-size

What is Eta squared? Can you help give an example to demonstrate what Eta squared measures. Distinguish between variability due to the IV and variability due to subject variables.

Answer (score 1):

As [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Eta-squared_.28.CE.B72.29):

> Eta-squared describes the ratio of variance explained in the dependent variable by a predictor while controlling for other predictors.

You can have an $\eta^2$ for a specific IV while controlling for other IVs or while controlling for subject variables, or you can have one for subject variables while controlling for other IVs. Each pair of nested models will give rise to its own effect size. Calculate and report the effect sizes that make sense in your analysis.